# Prove altered version of Eisenstein's criterion

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x)=a_0 +a_1x+\dots +a_nx^m \in\mathbb Z[x]$.

Suppose $\exists p$ prime: $p\mid a_1$, $p\mid a_2$, $\dots$, $p\mid a_n$, but $p^2 \nmid a_n$ and $p\nmid a_0$.

Prove $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

*Note that this is not Eisentein's criterion, but it is very close.*

---

"Proof"  (by contradiction)

*We assume $f(x)=a_0 +a_1x+\dots +a_nx^m \in\mathbb Z[x]$,
$\exists p$ prime: $p\mid a_1$, $p\mid a_2$, $\dots$, $p\mid a_n$, but $p^2 \nmid a_n$ and $p\nmid a_0$, 
and $f(x)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.*

if $f(x) $ is red. over $\mathbb{Q}$ we know it will be red in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ so $\exists g(x),h(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ s.t.
$$ f(x)=g(x)b(x) \text{ where } 1 \leq \deg g(x),\deg h(x) <n$$

Say $g(x)=b_rx^n+\dots+ b_0$ and $h(x)=c_sx^s+\dots +c_0$
now, $$ 
                  p\nmid a_0 \equiv \neg (p\mid c_0 t_0)\equiv \neg  (p\mid c_0 \vee p\mid t_0)\equiv p\nmid c_0 \wedge p\nmid t_0 
                        $$

$$p^2 \nmid a_n\equiv p^2 \nmid c_s t_r \equiv p^2 \nmid c_s \wedge p^2 \nmid c_r$$

also, $p\mid a_n$ so $p\neq 0,\pm1 $ so $p\mid c_r r_s $

$\vdots$

*Contradiction somewhere*

$\vdots$

Comment: Will it be easier to look at the reciprocal polynomial ? That it, replace $x$ by $1/x$ and make it a polynomial suitably. And then we can apply Eisenstein criterion. I might be missing details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment into an answer

Let  $g(x) = x^mf(x^{-1}) = a_0 x^m+\cdots+ a_n$ be the reciprocal polynomial of $f(x)$. Note that this is a polynomial with coefficients in reverse order of $f(x)$. And in this particular case $g(x)$ is irreducible by Eisenstein criterion.

We claim: If reciprocal polynomial of $f(x)$ is irreducible then $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Proof: For the sake of contradiction assume $f(x)$ is irreducible. Let $g(x)= a(x) b(x)$ with $\deg a(x)= i$ and $\deg b(x)= m - i, 0< i < n$. Then $g(x)= x^m a(x^{-1}) b(x^{-1})$. So $f(x^{-1}) = a(x^{-1})b(x^{-1)}$. And since $x$ is treated as a formal symbol that will imply $f(x)$ is reducible. Which finishes the proof.

Though if you don't want to use Eisenstein your strategy might work, I will think about it.